# How would you solve the following Golang challenge?

Tags: go

I have to solve following TreeHouse Go challenge, but I'm stuck in the Print method.

The requirement:

> In the `clock` and `calendar` packages, we've defined `Clock` and `Calendar` types, both of which have a `Display` method that you can call to print them.
>   In the `schedule` package, define a `Displayable` interface that is satisfied by the `Display` methods on both the `Clock` and `Calendar` types. (Don't make any changes to the `clock` or `calendar` packages.) Then, still in the `schedule` package, define a `Print` function that takes a `Displayable` value and calls `Display` on it.

clock.go:

```
package clock

import "fmt"

type Clock struct {
  Hours int
  Minutes int
}

func (c Clock) Display() {
  fmt.Printf("%02d:%02d", c.Hours, c.Minutes)
}
```

calendar.go:

```
package calendar

import "fmt"

type Calendar struct {
  Year int
  Month int
  Day int
}

func (c Calendar) Display() {
  fmt.Printf("%04d-%02d-%02d", c.Year, c.Month, c.Day)
}
```

schedule.go:

```
package schedule

// DECLARE A Displayable INTERFACE HERE
type Displayable interface {
    Display()
}

// DECLARE A Print FUNCTION HERE (I'm stuck here)
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
func Print(d Displayable) {
     d.Display()
}
```

Comment: I tried the same before but it didn't work, but now when I copied and pasted it, it worked. May be there was a typo. 
Thank you!